# Lua: %w+ и русский

Tags: lua

При попытке применить шаблон `%w+` к русскому тексту, он ничего не находит (т. .е `string.find('Строка для проверки', '%w+')` вернёт `nil, nil`). Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: в луа регулярки очень кастрированны, прийдется написать этот кусочек на си

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В винде просто пишешь `os.setlocale("")`, после этого `%w+` находит русские слова

В линуксе всё сложнее, потому что тексты там в кодировке UTF-8, которая не однобайтная

```
-- ищем русские слова в этой строке, как будто по паттерну %w+
local str = 'Строка для проверки'

local function is_russian_letter(char)
   local c = char:byte() * 256 + char:byte(-1)
   return c >= 0xD090 and c <= 0xD18F or c == 0xD081 or c == 0xD191
end

for word in str:gsub('[^\128-\191][\128-\191]*',
   function(c)
      return (c:find'%w' or is_russian_letter(c)) and '\0'..c..'\0'
   end):gsub('%z%z', ''):gmatch'%z(.-)%z'
do
   print(word)
end
```

Comment: Это, конечно, хорошо, но хотелось бы кроссплатформенное решение.

Comment: ну тогда конвертируй входные строки к какой-то одной кодировке и используй общий код обработки.  а когда будешь выводить строки обратно (на экран, в файл) - конвертируй их обратно в родную кодировку ОС.

Answer (score 2):

Один из вариантов: использовать шаблон `%S+`, т.е. захватить непробельные символы (захватит и знаки препинания).

Comment: Ну, если решение должно быть простым и кроссплатформенным, даже в ущерб правильности, то я бы использовал шаблон `[%w\128-\255]+`, чтобы были захвачены только английские буквы, цифры и все символы за пределами 7-битного ASCII.  При таком шаблоне знаки препинания и пробелы захвачены не будут.  И такой шаблон будет работать и в винде, и в линуксе.  Ошибочность шаблона, например, в том, что будет захвачен знак "евро" (а знак доллара - не будет).

Answer (score 2):

`os.setlocale("", 'ctype')` чтоб десятичный разделитель не изменился

Answer (score 1):

Вся проблема в том, что шаблон `%w` находит только латинские буквы и цифры:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789
```

Нужно сделать свой шаблон, например:

```
[а-Я%d]+
```

Но и у этого есть свои минусы. На некоторых кодировках тот шаблон не работает, а этот очень длинный:

```
[йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмить1234567890]
```